# Is Horde an acceptable framework for PHP groupware development?

Tags: php, frameworks, horde

I'm working on this project and the customer wants it to integrate with a groupware package including bulk email, calendars, and task lists. He has heard about [Horde](http://www.horde.org/) and [Horde GroupWare](http://www.horde.org/groupware/) and is interested in using that.

Do you have any developer related experience with Horde? If so, then what were your findings? Did you find it to be stable? What about the framework/API? Was it easy to integrate with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise this is a late answer, so your question may've been otherwise answered by now, but:

An application I've been involved with used Horde quite extensively, specifically the webmail aspects. Framework/API/integration wise, it's quite a headache - there's a lot of code in Horde, which makes it unmanageable rather quickly if you do actually have to go in and touch the code frequently.

If what you want is less tweaking, more using, then you've got a powerful tool at your disposal. The *company* I work for use it extensively for their purposes and are quite happy.

I'd guess that's more comparable to what you want, so I'd say go ahead.

Comment: Thanks for answering. In the end, I found it to be such a nightmare to install that I couldn't recommend it.

Comment: Oh my. Sorry to hear that. Hope you found a suitable alternative :) Good luck with your projects!

Answer (score 0):

Horde is a suitable framework and application system for your own custom apps or for enhancing existing modules.

http://wiki.horde.org/CreatingYourFirstModule

Or: wiki.horde.org/PopulatingYourFirstModule

API Docs: http://dev.horde.org/